# Refreshing Finder window view after sorting files

Tags: applescript

I have a simple script:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set sort column of list view options of Finder window 1 to size column
end tell
```

It works, but the problem is that the window is stale and does not immediately reflect the new order of the files. I have to change the target of the window to a different directory and then navigate back to see the files sorted by size.

Comment: Apologies if I'm completely off the point, but `do shell script "killall Finder"` after `end tell` refresh it for you?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a proper solution to this. Here is a workaround hack:

[Applescripts not working in Finder since Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/140906/applescripts-not-working-in-finder-since-mavericks?answertab=active#tab-top)